# putting mutler in a seperate file and using module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to refactor my code. I am working on a house market place website and added the mutler library to upload images

listingRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer({dest: './backend/uploads'})

const {createListing, getListings, getListing,deleteListing} = require('../controllers/listingController')




const { protect } = require('../middleware/authMiddleware')

router.get('/', protect, getListings)
router.post('/',upload.single('imgUrl'),protect, createListing)
router.get('/:id',protect, getListing)
router.delete('/:id',protect,deleteListing)


module.exports = router
```

Im adding upload.single to the post request in my listing controller to upload images. It works but I want to separate the code to upload images and put it in another folder like how authMiddleware is (I copied authMiddleware from another project).

I created a file called imagesMiddleware.js and added the multer code inside

```
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer({dest: './backend/uploads'})
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')



const uploadImg = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

return upload.single('imgUrl')
    

})

module.exports = {uploadImg}
```

I then refactor the listingRoutes.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()


const {createListing, getListings, getListing,deleteListing} = require('../controllers/listingController')




const { protect } = require('../middleware/authMiddleware')
const { image } = require('../middleware/imagesMiddleware')
router.get('/', protect, getListings)
router.post('/',image, protect, createListing)
router.get('/:id',protect, getListing)
router.delete('/:id',protect,deleteListing)


module.exports = router
```

I get this error in my console

```
/Users/styles/Programming/house-ecommerce/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:211
[0]         throw new Error(msg);
[0]         ^
[0] 
[0] Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
```

I'm still learning javascript so help will be appreciated

Comment: You're exporting `uploadImg` in `imagesMiddleware.js` and then importing `image` in your route file, which is obviously undefined.

Comment: I changed it from {image} to { uploadImg } and it’s not uploading any data

Comment: Well, that's a different story; your code has a bug that is preventing files from being uploaded, but you're one step closer to a perfect application (you replaced the error with your intended code).